# PHP Soap Client Fails in PHP version 7, but works in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have a SOAP Client running in PHP 7.2 like this:

```php
$wsdl = "http://ws4.altotrack.com/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc?wsdl";
$this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 
            'exceptions' => 1, 
            'trace' => 1,
            'encoding'=>'UTF-8',            
        ]); 

// This is generated dynamically but with the expected format and it's ok
$xml_string = '<registro><systemUser>AltoWS</systemUser><password>$Alt0WS</password><movil><proveedor><registro><systemUser>...</systemUser><password>...</password><movil><proveedor>...</proveedor><dominio>...</dominio><nroSerie>...</nroSerie><codigo>...</codigo><latitud>...</latitud><longitud>...</longitud><altitud>...</altitud><velocidad>...</velocidad><rumbo>...</rumbo> <fechaHoraEvento>...</fechaHoraEvento><fechaHoraRecepcion>...</fechaHoraRecepcion></movil></registro>';

$soapvar     = new SoapVar($xml_string, XSD_STRING);
$xml_payload =  ['xmlSerializado' => $soapvar];

try {

    $result = $this->client->ProcessXML($xml_payload);
    dump($this->client->__getLastRequest());
    dump($this->client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
    //dump($this->client->__getLastResponse());
    //dump($this->client->__getLastResponseHeaders());

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {

    dump($fault);
}
```

This is the SOAP Envelope Request is generated:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ProcessXML>
          <ns1:xmlSerializado>
            <registro>
              <systemUser>...</systemUser>
              <password>...</password>
              <movil>
                <proveedor>...</proveedor>
                <dominio>...</dominio>
                <nroSerie>...</nroSerie>
                <codigo>...</codigo>
                <latitud>...</latitud>
                <longitud>...</longitud>
                <altitud>...</altitud>
                <velocidad>...</velocidad>
                <rumbo>...</rumbo>
                <fechaHoraEvento>...</fechaHoraEvento>
                <fechaHoraRecepcion>...</fechaHoraRecepcion>
              </movil>
            </registro>
          </ns1:xmlSerializado>
        </ns1:ProcessXML>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the request header:

```text
POST /WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: ws4.altotrack.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.10.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IServicePositions/ProcessXML
```

The result its always an Error, not SOAP Fault Exception, the response itself shoul be an OK but I get Error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <ProcessXMLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ProcessXMLResult>Error</ProcessXMLResult>
    </ProcessXMLResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I dont know why exactly the same code works fine in PHP 5.3.3, no changes made to SOAP Client or xml encoding algorithm, the Request output is the same:

```text
POST /WSPosiciones_WalmartMX/WSPosiciones_WalmartMX.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: ws4.altotrack.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IServicePositions/ProcessXML
```

The same request using PHP 5.3 gives me this response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <ProcessXMLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ProcessXMLResult>Ok</ProcessXMLResult>
    </ProcessXMLResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I don't know why and I don't know how to debug this behavior, does any else have this issue?

I tried changing the context, using other options in the client, with Nusoap Library, using Class Map instead but always get an Error response.

```php
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);

$options = [
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'trace' => 1,
    'encoding' =>'UTF-8',        
    'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'stream_context' => $context
];
```

I'm not sure if this is related to PHP or there is another thing going here, but the funny fact it's that was working fine until last PHP update like a week ago or so.

```text
Upgrade: 
....
php7.2-xmlrpc:amd64 (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2), 
php7.2-soap:amd64 (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
End-Date: 2020-01-16  00:27:23
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well for starters, don't generate XML manually. You've got a missing bracket in your XML.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault when I edit the content in <ns1:xmlSerializado> tag for hide the real info.
In the XML that its generated there is no missing bracket. Updated.

I also used SimpleXml to create the XML Document for this task, also didn't work.